# How to set default home page in apache

Tags: apache, web-services, .htaccess

I have several folders and pages on my site and it's working well while calling it directly (like `mydomain.com/forum or mydomain/tmp/file.html`).
 
But when calling just `mydomain.com` apache tries to find `mydomain/index.html/` folder, while there is `index.html` file in the root directory and no index.html folder. As the result 404 error.
 Where to change apache settings? (only `.htaccess` available, it's virtual hosting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely there is some rule adding trailing slash. You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to remove a trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ /$1 [R=302,L,NE]
```